# Restart Oozie in AWS EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, oozie, emr

I would like to change the "from address for a Oozie Email action and made some changes to oozie-site.xml. I am not sure how to apply the changes that I have made.Can we start and stop services such as Oozie in AWS EMR?

Thanks,
Sai

Comment: That depends on the AMI version of EMR you are using. Can you specify that ?

Answer (score 1):

`ps -ef|grep oozie` -- just to check the name of the oozie service

```
sudo stop oozie

sudo start oozie
```

Comment: Bharath - If this Solution worked for you, can you mark it as Accepted

Comment: does it affect the existing running jobs?

Comment: @karthikeayan - Restarting the Oozie, doesn't seem to affect the running jobs. Tested on AWS EMR 5.11.2, oozie 4.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

At least on the EMR 4.x and 5.x series releases, simply issuing the commands `sudo oozie stop` and `sudo oozie start` will restart the Oozie server.

There's also a helpful blog post that talks about getting started with Oozie on EMR that was recently posted to the AWS Big Data Blog:

https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/TxZ4KDBGBMZYJL/Use-Apache-Oozie-Workflows-to-Automate-Apache-Spark-Jobs-and-more-on-Amazon-EMR

Comment: 5.x seems to not be `oozie stop` but `stop oozie` instead. Not sure about 4.x